# Output dictonary to a table: key order issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a JSON file and I want to output the data to a table in Google Sheet. Since the data order is not guaranteed, I need to search for the corresponding row for the second and subsequent data set (Tuesday data from my example below).

Apart from looping thru the first column, is there a faster or more elegant way to do this?

```
function test(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SSheet=ss.getActiveSheet();  
  var data={Monday:{Apple:2, Orange:3}, Tuesday:{Orange:4, Apple:5}};//intentionally swap the key
  var row=2;  
  var column=2;
  var bWriteHeader=true;
  for (const g in data){
    SSheet.getRange(1,column).setValue(g)
    row=2;
    for (const k in data[g]){
      if (bWriteHeader){
        SSheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(k);
        SSheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(data[g][k]);
         row++;
      }else{
        //Search for the corresponding row--- how to do it elegantly, apart from looping thru first column?
        SSheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(data[g][k]);
      }
    }
    bWriteHeader=false;
    column++;  
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
     Monday Tuesday
Apple   2    5
Orange  3    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

Although I'm not sure whether my proposed method is `more elegant way`, in this answer, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve a row header.
2. Retrieve a column header.
3. Create an array using the row header and column header.
4. Put the values to the active sheet.

In this flow, after the array was created, the array is put to the Spreadsheet. By this, I thought that the process cost will be lower than your script that `setValue` is used in a loop. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) When this flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = { Monday: { Apple: 2, Orange: 3 }, Tuesday: { Orange: 4, Apple: 5 } };//intentionally swap the key

  // 1. Retrieve a row header.
  var rowHeader = Object.keys(data).sort();

  // 2. Retrieve a column header.
  var colHeader = Object.keys(data[rowHeader[0]]).sort();

  // 3. Create an array using the row header and column header.
  var values = rowHeader.reduce((ar, k) => ar.concat([[k, ...colHeader.map(l => data[k][l])]]), [["", ...colHeader]]);
  var res = values[0].map((_, i) => values.map(r => r[i]));

  // 4. Put the values to the active sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

```js
var data = { Monday: { Apple: 2, Orange: 3 }, Tuesday: { Orange: 4, Apple: 5 } };//intentionally swap the key

// 1. Retrieve a row header.
var rowHeader = Object.keys(data).sort();

// 2. Retrieve a column header.
var colHeader = Object.keys(data[rowHeader[0]]).sort();

// 3. Create an array using the row header and column header.
var values = rowHeader.reduce((ar, k) => ar.concat([[k, ...colHeader.map(l => data[k][l])]]), [["", ...colHeader]]);
var res = values[0].map((_, i) => values.map(r => r[i]));
console.log(res)
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: @Tanaike.Thank you so much for the code and references. I got more than what I asked for! I don't understand the code for `reduce` and `res`. I will need to google these with more reading. .

Comment: @Leon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.